# What is the best way to support parsing multiple languages in ANTLR?

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, antlr

I have written an application in Java that allows the user to enter a statement like:

**show photos with tag "..."**

I use ANTLR to write a lexer/parser to parse the above input which is in English, obviously. I want to allow the user to enter the same statement in their native language (for example German). Is there a best practice for doing this in ANTLR?

My first thought was to write a lexer/parser for each supported language and name the generated classes with locale-specific suffixes and load the appropriate class based on the user's locale. However, before I recreate the ResourceBundle's loading algorithm, I wondered if there were some ANTLR features and best practices to make this easier.

Comment: You shouldn't use programming language parsers for natural language. Instead explore the field of NLP (natural language processing) for your task.

Comment: I agree with you, Mike. With my simpler requirements than the above example and some knowledge of ANTRL, I chose an expedient solution. I guess it's time look into NLP implementations. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing in the ANTLR API that makes internationalization easier. I'd just create multiple grammars. And I agree with Mike: ANTLR isn't well suited to parse natural (human) languages.